# Dynamically append JSX component as child of specific DOM element

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

The problem is to attach a React component (which contents change on props change) as a child of a DOM element which is already created by another component (a component which is imported and which I cannot modify directly) and which is selected by id or classname.

So similar to document.getElementById('myId').appendChild().

Is there a React way of doing this? 
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).appendChild() would apparently be too easy.

Comment: That's not how React works. You have to avoid using jquery patterns in React.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) in React to render to an outside area. In this case, since it's another React component, you need to have a way to know when it's ready, and you need the target DOM element not to be rerendered by React.

**Example:**

```js
const Show = ({ count }) => (
  <div>{count}</div>
);

const InnerTarget = <div id="target"></div>;

class Target extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.ready();
  }

  render() {
    return InnerTarget;
  }
}

class Increment extends React.Component {
  state = {
    count: 0,
    ready: false
  };
  
  increment = () => this.setState(({ count }) => ({
    count: count + 1
  }));
  
  ready = () => this.setState({ ready: true });
  
  render() {
    const { count, ready } = this.state;
    
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={this.increment}>Inc</button>
        <Target ready={this.ready} />
        {ready &&
        ReactDOM.createPortal(
          <Show count={count} />,
          document.querySelector('#target')
        )
        }
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Increment />,
  app
);
```

```css
#target {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```